# Media query bagunçando uma outra media query

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Bom Dia,

Estou com um problema com algumas *media queries* 
comecei fazendo as *media queries* na parte de desktop com as seguintes medidas que funcionaram  perfeitamente:

```
1024x600 
1024x768 
1280x768 
1440x900
1600x900 
1680x1050 
1920x1080    
1920x1200
```

abaixo tem um exemplo de como utilizei uma delas:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) , screen and (max-height: 600px){
...
}
```

Essas *media query* estavam funcionando. Porém quando comecei a fazer as *media queries* para tablets as de desktops bagunçaram não sei porque abaixo estão as medidas que usei para as *media queries*:

```
533x853
600x800
600x1024
603x966
768x1024
800x1280
```

Abaixo esta o código CSS que usei:

```css
@media only screen and(min-width:603px),(min-height: 966px){
...
}
```

Só lembrando que as *media queries*  de desktops estão em um arquivo separado das do tablet.

segue abaixo minha *media queries* referente a do desktop:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) , screen and (max-width: 600px){

    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    }
    .nomes{
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .botao-circulo{
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left:-15px;
    }

    #header {
        height: 750px;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(1.8);
    }


    #bg-video{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -50;
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin-left: 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 90%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 175%; 
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }


    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }


    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 330%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    .linha-team{
        width: 40%;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }



    #footer .copyright {
        left: 38%;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-height: 768px){
    #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
        left: -300px;
        top: 250%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        left: -300px;
        top: 65%;
        transform:scale(0.6);
    }

}

/*notebook 13 polegadas*/
@media screen and (min-width:1280px),(min-height: 800px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 85%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 265%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

}

@media screen and (max-width:1366px),(max-height: 768px){
    /*    #fundo-transparente-icones{
            left: -180px;
            top: 90%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }

         #fundo-transparente-parcerias{
            left: -180px;
            top: 275%;
            transform:scale(0.7);
        }*/

}

@media screen and (max-width:1440px),(max-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 26%;
    } 
}

@media screen and (min-width:1600px),(min-height: 900px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 32%;
    } 

    .setas{
        position: absolute;
        top: 60px;
        left: 14%;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width:1680px),(max-height: 1050px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px),(min-height: 1080px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
       width: 100%;
    }

     .setas{
        left: 18%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1920px),(min-height: 1200px){
    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 13%;
    }

    #bg-video{
       width: 100%;
    }

     .setas{
        left: 18%;
    }
}
```

e também a minha *media queries* do tablet que esta bagunçando minha *media queries*  do desktop:

```
@media screen and(max-width:533px),(max-height: 853px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 5%;
    }

    #menu ul li a{

        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 4px;
    }

    #seta-esquerda{
        right: 35px;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        left: 35px;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3.4);
    }

    .nomes{
        font-size: 4.3em;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }

    .texto1 {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .image.ico {

        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 175px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 80%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .main {
        padding: 6em 0 4em 0;
    }



    .main.style2 {
        background-color: #333;
        color:#fff;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        height: 600px;
        opacity: 0.95;
        border-bottom: 15px solid #f80;
        border-top: 15px solid #f80;

    }

    .main.style2{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        border:3px solid #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        border-radius: 6px;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"]:hover,.jogos-botao{
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #333;
        transition:0.5s;
    }

}

@media screen and(max-width:600px),(max-height: 800px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 10%;
    }

    .image.ico {
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .container > p{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Gabriola;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}


@media screen and(min-width:600px),(min-height: 1024px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 5%;
    }


    #seta-esquerda{
        right: 30px;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        left: 30px;
    }

    .setas{

        left: -1%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3);
    }

    .image.ico {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 90%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 3.5em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }

}


@media screen and(min-width:603px),(min-height: 966px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 5%;
    }


    #seta-esquerda{
        right: 30px;
    }

    #seta-direita{
        left: 30px;
    }

    .setas{

        left: -1%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3);
    }

    .image.ico {
        margin: 3em 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 200px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 90%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 4em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }
}


@media screen and(min-width:768px),(min-height: 1024px){
    #menu ul {
        left: 15%;
    }

    video {
        transform:scaley(3);
    }

    .image.ico {
        margin: 3em 0 1em 0;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 265px;
    }

    .image.ico img {
        width: 60%;
    }

    .botao-mais input[type="button"],.mais{
        margin-left: 140%; 
    }

    #fundo-transparente-icones{
        position: absolute;
        left: -180px;
        top: 80%;
        transform:scale(0.8);
        z-index: -200;
    }

    .main .jogos-nomes{
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 4.5em;
    }

    .texto-jogos{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin-top: 120px;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }

    .botaozao input[type="button"],.jogos-botao{
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-top: 30px;   
        font-size: 1.7em;

    }

}
```

Comment: Só uma dica: Não confunda "design" com "designer".

Comment: ok! obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Cuidado que com `width` de `800px` por exemplo entras nas duas *media query*

Comment: Era mais fácil se explicasses o que queres fazer e o que tens dentro das *media query*

Comment: "ah" sim irei editar a pergunta agora mesmo um instante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kirito o problema está fácil de ver, algumas resoluções de ecrã acabam por entrar nas duas *media*.

Por exemplo, `1680x1050` e `768x1024` encaixam as duas na *media query*:

```
@media only screen and(min-width:603px),(min-height: 966px){
...
}
```

Porque ao definires um `min-width:603px` estás a dizer que todas as resoluções de ecrã com mais de `603px` têm de obedecer as regras dentro desse *media* e, por isso, no caso da resolução de ecrã `1680x1050` entram nas duas *media*.

Comment: Nossa amigo bem sacado não tinha percebido isso irei testar agora mesmo e já te dou um retorno

Comment: ola amigo testei aqui e não funcionou acho que não estou fazendo certo irei postar o meu cédigo desktop e tablet para você poder dar uma olhada.

Comment: Acho é que não estás a entender o funcionamento disso tudo. Por exemplo se queres que num ecrã de `533x853` se comporte de uma forma que pretendes tens de fazer assim: `@media screen and (max-width: 533px) , screen and (max-height: 853px){ //código para essa largura de ecrã}`

Comment: Ou seja, para ecrãs com um máximo de `533x853`. Ecrãs menores que esse também entram nesse código e ecrãs superiores a esse não entram.

Comment: Se ao invés usar o `min-with: 533px` estás a dizer que todos os ecrãs com resolução superior a `533px` entra nesse código.

Comment: Estás a perceber o que quer dizer?

Comment: acho que agora sim amigo se não me engano estou errando mesmo e no css do tablet no caso estou verificando e pensando na forma aqui

Comment: acho que agora vai funcionar

Comment: Diz se funcionou depois

Comment: funcionou obrigadooo

Comment: De nada amigo :)

Answer (score 0):

Se adicionar um `max-width`, quem sabe resolva seu problema...

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 603px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
     codigo......
}
```

Comment: "hmm" mais vou testar só que e o meu max-height onde ele fica eu preciso dele mais irei testar isso agora.